# Trimming preceding zeros from time format

Tags: php

Is there a function that exists to convert a time stamp such as

```
00:42:00 to 42:00 
or 
01:25:51 to 1:25:51 
or 
00:03:40 to 3:40 
or
00:00:08 to 8
```

and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php), and specify 0 and : in the character mask. I.e.:

```
ltrim($time, '0:');
```

Comment: That should be `ltrim`, so that the `0` isn't stripped off the end of `00:03:40`.